# Keep the broweser open, after terminating the python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome

I want to open google chrome browser and go to facebook and terminate the python program but keep the google chrome window open until I manually close it. Please give me your own idea/Program with the above said as the aim.

I expect the chrome window to remain open after the program terminates, but it closes automatically after the program terminates.

Comment: Let me know about further clarification of the question.

Comment: Are you using selenium?

Comment: I tried with selenium. If you could provide code involving selenium ill try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `os.system()` should be avoided because it is platform dependent and because it isn't secure: if you use `os.system('start chrome "%s"') % url` where `url` is a string submitted by the user, someone can enter `www.facebook.com" && shutdown /s /t "0` Facebook will open in a new Chrome window but then the computer will shut down.

The easiest way to open a new page in the browser is:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("www.facebook.com")
```

It remains open when the Python script terminates.

Comment: Security perspective makes absolute sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works on windows!

```py
import os
os.system("start chrome \"www.facebook.com\"")
```

This shall open a chrome browser with the Facebook URL using cmd and it remains open even after the termination of the program.

Comment: OMG Thanks it works. Can you give some code to open notepad, because it also opens and closes it if the program terminates

Comment: @KamaleshPathy You can use `os.system("start notepad")`.

Comment: For that, you can use Subprocess as it provides more flexibility with outputs.
```subprocess.Popen(["Notepad"])```

Comment: @AkashGovind Agree, but I'm not sure if subprocesses remain alive when you exit the Python script. (But it seems that dhey do.)

Comment: @AkashGovind `subprocess.Popen(["Notepad"])` still have the same problem

Comment: @MaxiMouse Yeah, you are right about that. Hence, there are no pros of using subprocess in this case.

Comment: @KamaleshPathy, it works for me. My program exits after starting notepad.